# Delete Row in VBA not working from row 3584

Tags: vba, row

I want to check all rows in my excel file, if a cell contains a certain value : delete it.

My code works until the row 3584, after, the `Rows(ActiveCell.row).Delete` doesn't works...

I doesn't have error message, and when I want to debug manually with "F8", the row go to the next without delete it.

Variables values at 3584 iteration :

```
i = 3584;
j = 3614;
ligne = 3584;
lastRow = 78216;
Var = "PROPERTY NAME = ..."
```

Can you help me please ?
I use Excel 2007.

My code :

```
Sub ParcoursLignes()

'Selection de la feuille
Sheets("Feuil3").Select

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim ligne As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

Var = 0
nomMachine = 0
nomMachine_brut = 0
ligneSupprime = 0
ligne = 0
i = 0
j = 0
lastRow = 0

'Selection de la 1ère cellule
Range("A1").Select

'Recupère la ligne de la dernière valeur de la colonne A
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

For i = 1 To 40000 Step 1

If j <= 40000 Then

j = j + 1

'Récupérer le numéro de la ligne
ligne = ActiveCell.row


'Récupère le contenu de la cellule
Var = ActiveCell.Value

'test si la cellule contient "ip_address"
If Var Like "*ip_address*" Then

nommachine = toto
nomMachine_brut = 1010

ElseIf (Var Like "*PROPERTY*") Or (Var Like "*OBJECT*") Then
'Suppression de la ligne
Rows(ActiveCell.row).Delete
ligneSupprime = 1
End If

'Si ligneSupprime différent de 1
If ligneSupprime <> 1 Then
'Retour dans la colonne A
Range("A" & (ActiveCell.row + 1)).Select

Else
'retourne à la ligne précédente
i = i - 1
End If

ip = 0
Var = 0
nomMachine = 0
nomMachine_brut = 0
ligneSupprime = 0

Else
GoTo sortie
End If

Next i

sortie:

End Sub
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett : I've uploaded my file here : http://sendbox.fr/pro/8fwgfaxtqpm2/test.xlsm.html

Comment: I've deleted some sheets, and now it works !!! Maybe cause by a lack of RAM...  Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing you'll probably run into the same error eventually -
You're moving from row 1 to the bottom and deleting rows by the looks of it.
Imagine you've got an error on row 1 and another on row 3 - you delete row 1 and the row 3 error is now on row 2 and the code misses it and deletes row 3 instead.

Comment: You're also using ranges such as **Rows(ActiveCell.row).Delete**.  This will affect the rows on the selected sheet which may not be the sheet you want.  Use code such as **Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(1).Delete**.

Comment: As DarrenBartrup-Cook commented, if you are working from the top down and deleting rows, you may be skipping rows because you deleted one above it.  To avoid this, you should work from the bottom up.  E.g. `For i=40000 to 1 step -1`

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to move backward in loop

```
 For i = 40000 To 1 Step -1
```